# How to list all possibilities from recursive tree?

Tags: php, algorithm, tree

I've got this initial data:

```
$h = [
    'id' => 'h',
    'name' => 'H',
    'config' => [],
];

$g = [
    'id' => 'g',
    'name' => 'G',
    'config' => [],
];

$f = [
    'id' => 'f',
    'name' => 'F',
    'config' => [
        [
            ['id' => $g['id'], 'quantity' => 1],
        ],
        [
            ['id' => $h['id'], 'quantity' => 2],
        ],
    ],
];

$e = [
    'id' => 'e',
    'name' => 'E',
    'config' => [],
];

$d = [
    'id' => 'd',
    'name' => 'D',
    'config' => [
        [
            ['id' => $e['id'], 'quantity' => 1],
            ['id' => $f['id'], 'quantity' => 3],
        ],
    ],
];

$c = [
    'id' => 'c',
    'name' => 'C',
    'config' => [
        [
            ['id' => $f['id'], 'quantity' => 1],
        ],
        [
            ['id' => $e['id'], 'quantity' => 1],
        ],
    ],
];

$b = [
    'id' => 'b',
    'name' => 'B',
    'config' => [
        [
            ['id' => $c['id'], 'quantity' => 1],
        ],
    ],
];

$a = [
    'id' => 'a',
    'name' => 'A',
    'config' => [
        [
            ['id' => $d['id'], 'quantity' => 1],
        ],
        [
            ['id' => $b['id'], 'quantity' => 1],
        ],
    ],
];
```

I will explain how "config" works:

- it's an array of possibilities (OR) => for example **from $c we can have $f OR $e**
- inside these possibilities there's an array of AND =>, for example, **from $d we have only one possibility with $e AND $f**
- when the config is empty, it's a leaf so we can stop
- and the tricky part (I think) is that we can have quantity inside each config which means **from $f we can have $g once OR $h twice** and **from $d we have $e once AND $f 3 times**

What I want to achieve with my algorithm is having output like this :

```
$possibilities = [
    [
        [
            'id' => 'a',
            ...
        ],
        [
            'id' => 'b',
            'parent' => 'a',
            ...
        ],
        [
            'id' => 'c',
            'parent' => 'b',
            ...
        ],
        [
            'id' => 'f',
            'parent' => 'c'
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            'id' => 'a',
            ...
        ],
        [
            'id' => 'b',
            'parent' => 'a',
            ...
        ],
        [
            'id' => 'c',
            'parent' => 'b',
            ...
        ],
        [
            'id' => 'e',
            'parent' => 'c'
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            'id' => 'a',
            ...
        ],
        [
            'id' => 'd',
            'parent' => 'a',
            ...
        ],
        [
            'id' => 'e',
            'parent' => 'd',
            ...
        ],
        [
            'id' => 'f-1',
            'parent' => 'd',
            ...
        ],
        [
            'id' => 'f-2',
            'parent' => 'd',
            ...
        ],
        [
            'id' => 'f-3',
            'parent' => 'd',
            ...
        ],
        [
            'id' => 'g',
            'parent' => 'f-1',
            ...
        ],
        [
            'id' => 'g',
            'parent' => 'f-2',
            ...
        ],
        [
            'id' => 'g',
            'parent' => 'f-3',
            ...
        ]
    ],
    ...
];
```

So I want to extract and list any possibility and having the parent node (including its number in case quantity > 1)
So far I've tried something like this :

```
global $datas;
$datas = compact($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g, $h);

function formatTree($tree)
{
    if (empty($tree['config'])) {
        return [$tree];
    }

    $config = $tree['config'];
    unset($tree['config']);

    $tree2 = [$tree];

    foreach ($config as $item) {
        $sub = formatTree($item);
        $tree2 = array_merge($tree2, $sub);
    }

    return $tree2;
}


function preparePossibilities($item)
{
    $possibilities = [];

    if (empty($item['config'])) {
        return [$item];
    }

    $config = $item['config'];
    unset($item['config']);

    foreach ($config as $or) {
        $finalOr = [];
        foreach ($or as $and) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < ($and['quantity'] ?? 1); $i++) {
                $finalOr[] = $and;
            }
        }
        $item['config'] = $finalOr;
        $possibilities[] = $item;
    }

    return $possibilities;
}

function are_same($trees)
{
    $id = null;
    foreach ($trees as $tree) {
        $oldId = $id;
        $id = $tree[0]['id'];
        if (isset($oldId) && $oldId !== $id) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

function getAllTrees($id)
{
    global $datas;
    $data = current(array_filter($datas, static function ($d) use ($id) {
        return $d['id'] === $id;
    }));

    $multiplePossibilities = preparePossibilities($data);

    $allTrees = [];

    foreach ($multiplePossibilities as $possibility) {
        if (empty($possibility['config'])) {
            return [$possibility];
        }

        $config = $possibility['config'];
        unset($possibility['config']);

        $trees = [];
        foreach ($config as $i => $and) {
            $subTrees = getAllTrees($and['id']);

            foreach ($subTrees as $subTree) {
                $trees[$i][] = $subTree;
            }

        }

        $trees = array_values($trees);

        if (count($trees) === 1) {
            foreach ($trees as $tree) {
                foreach ($tree as $t) {
                    $newP = $possibility;
                    $newP['config'] = [];
                    $newP['config'][] = $t;
                    $allTrees[] = $newP;
                }
            }
        } elseif (are_same($trees)) {
            $newP = $possibility;
            $newP['config'] = $trees;
            $allTrees[] = $newP;
        } else {
            $newP = $possibility;
            $newP['config'] = [];
            foreach ($trees as $tree) {
                if (count($tree) === 1) {
                    $newP['config'][] = $tree[0];
                } else {
                    foreach ($tree as $t) {
                        $p3 = $newP;
                        $p3['config'][] = $t;
                        $allTrees[] = $p3;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    return $allTrees;
}

foreach (getAllTrees('a') as $tree) {
    var_dump(formatTree($tree));
}
```

And the output is :

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "a"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "A"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "d"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "D"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "e"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "E"
    ["config"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "f"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "F"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "g"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "G"
    ["config"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "a"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "A"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "d"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "D"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "e"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "E"
    ["config"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "f"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "F"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "h"
      ["name"]=>
      string(1) "H"
      ["config"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
  }
  [5]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "h"
      ["name"]=>
      string(1) "H"
      ["config"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
  }
}
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "a"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "A"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "d"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "D"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "e"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "E"
    ["config"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "f"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "F"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "g"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "G"
    ["config"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "a"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "A"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "d"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "D"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "e"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "E"
    ["config"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "f"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "F"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "h"
      ["name"]=>
      string(1) "H"
      ["config"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
  }
  [5]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "h"
      ["name"]=>
      string(1) "H"
      ["config"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
  }
}
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "a"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "A"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "d"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "D"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "e"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "E"
    ["config"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "f"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "F"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "g"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "G"
    ["config"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "a"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "A"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "d"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "D"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "e"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "E"
    ["config"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "f"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "F"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "h"
      ["name"]=>
      string(1) "H"
      ["config"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
  }
  [5]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "h"
      ["name"]=>
      string(1) "H"
      ["config"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
  }
}
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "a"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "A"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "b"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "B"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "c"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "C"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "f"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "F"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "g"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "G"
    ["config"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "a"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "A"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "b"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "B"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "c"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "C"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "f"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "F"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "h"
      ["name"]=>
      string(1) "H"
      ["config"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
  }
  [5]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "h"
      ["name"]=>
      string(1) "H"
      ["config"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
  }
}
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "a"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "A"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "b"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "B"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "c"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "C"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "e"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "E"
    ["config"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, if I were you I would start to break down the problem and simplify your test data and then make it more complex as you go. You could also create a node class that is capable of adding other nodes and printing its child nodes. Regarding the counting of 2f or 1g etc. this is just an array of options and you can do a basic for loop, no? Sift through all the options. Each time you add another node.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'll try your advice ! I already tried to break down but at some point, when more complex I can't make it work... But I'll try the node class and looping over options